# Foreach Sorting

Tags: php, api, sorting

I'm not too sure if this is possible but I will try to explain it anyhow,

We are trying to make a page for our guild and we want it to display the Average Item level Equipped along with their name e.g.

```
Name | iLvL 
Bob    262
Sam    159
```

We are currently running a script that is doing the following :

```
$members = $guild->getMembers();
```

This basically gets a list of all members in our guild - We are then iterating through with a foreach loop and making another call to get bits of information

```
//Character Arrays
foreach($members as $member) {

//Get character information
$mrank = $member['rank'];
$mname = $member['character']['name'];
$mgender = $member['character']['gender'];
$mlevel = $member['character']['level'];
$mrace = $member['character']['race'];
$character = $armory->getCharacter($mname);
$gear = $character->getGear();
$milevel = $gear['averageItemLevelEquipped'];
echo '<td><div align="center" class="style1">'. $mname .'</div></td>';
echo '<td><div align="center" class="style1">'. $milevel .'</div></td> ';
```

The only problem is because we iterate through them singular im not too sure how I could sort the Average Item Level into highest to lowest - I've heard of things like rsort but i couldn't seem to get it to work and I was wondering if anyone would be able to lend a hand with this.

Thanks

Comment: Where does `$character`come from?

Comment: $character = $armory->getCharacter($mname); that is the second call it makes to get all the other information about the character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend creating an array out of the data you have there, with a sub-array for each person. Also create an array merely consisting of the averageItemLevelEquipped values, and then use that as the index array when runnning `array_multisort`. It would look something like this:

```
$resourcearray = array();
$indexarray = array();

foreach($members as $member) {
    //Get character information
    $mrank = $member['rank'];
    $mname = $member['character']['name'];
    $milevel = $gear['averageItemLevelEquipped'];
    //and anything else you want to add goes here, of course
    array_push($resourcearray, array('rank' => $mrank, 'charname' => $mname, 'itemlevel' => $milevel));
    array_push($indexarray, $milevel);
}

array_multisort($indexarray, $resourcearray);

foreach($resourcearray as $resource) {
    echo '<td><div align="center" class="style1">'. $resource['charname'] .'</div></td>';
    echo '<td><div align="center" class="style1">'. $resource['itemlevel'] .'</div></td> ';
}
```

Comment: I agree with the guys below, of course, that one should try to solve this in SQL instead. I figured I'd still answer the question in a stricter way for reference, albeit a tad XY.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort members in your SQL-query.
If you want sort result array use uasort: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

Comment: Then one would have to join the character and member tables in SQL - one would have to assume that this possible, i.e. they have access to the contents of the getCharacter() function.

Answer (score 2):

```
$members = $guild->getMembers();
```

create another method;

```
$members = $guild->getMembersByiLvL();
```

Which adds the line `ORDER BY iLvL DESC` to an sql query.

As you do not show the class from which $guild is an object, I cannot say how easy it is to do this - but that would seem to be a more preferable means.

You could then go on to develop that method to do this:

```
$members = $guild->getMembersSorted('iLvL');
```

Edit: I am presuming your data is coming from a Mysql db here, so could be wrong of course ...

Answer (score 2):

`foreach` iterates over the input array without any modifications to the order.
so you need to either sort the input before the `foreach` or the the result of the foreach iteration.

usually it's better to sort the input before it is `foreach`ed, either by

1. sort the data when it is pulled from the database (SQL `ORDER BY` clause)
2. sorting the array (or array-like object) you want to iterate

for 2, there are a lot of sort functions for arrays in PHP (have a look at php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php ). for example, you could use `usort` like this:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
  if ($a['character']['level'] == $b['character']['level']) {
    return 0;
  }
  return ($a['character']['level'] < $b['character']['level']) ? -1 : 1;
}
$members = $guild->getMembers();

usort($members, 'cmp');

foreach ($members as $member) {
  //..
}
```

if you have access to the DB queries and usually need the data sorted in this way, it is better (better performance, better readability) to use the database side sorting in SQL.